# המבזבז אל יבזבז and the Guarantee of Wealth

Tags: talmud-gemara, money, tzedakah-charity, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

It says in Talmud that Chazal made a Takana in Usha that one should not give too much money to charity. Specifically more than one fifth.

Does the guarantee of wealth still apply to someone who gives more than one fifth?

One idea I had is that maybe it does apply but only after they are temporarily supported by others. (I may have heard this somewhere - if you know the source please comment)

Comment: I found that it says in Shulchan Aruch Harav that a person is allowed to give more than one fifth - which would imply that the blessing is still there.

Comment: Do you mean in Tanya?

Comment: What guarantee of wealth are you referring to?

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2012/03/21/giving-more-than-a-fifth-to-charity/

Comment: The Vilna Gaon talks about a guarantee

Comment: Also The GRAPKE brought the link I found it from. But that link seems to mistakenly quote it from Shulchan Arukh Harav. After my research I found it to be from Tanya indeed.

Comment: In Tanya it says that one can give more than a fifth to atone for his sins, as it is no different than spending on one’s personal needs. This would suggest that more than a fifth is considered personal spending, and thus not included in the guarantee.